# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\wamp64\www\dev\node_modules\.staging'

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, staging, bulma

Any one can help me with this npm error

npm version: 5.5.1,
node version: 8.9.1,
os: windows 10 64-bit

```
S C:\wamp64\www\dev> npm install bulma
npm ERR! path C:\wamp64\www\dev\node_modules\.staging
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 
'C:\wamp64\www\dev\node_modules\.staging'npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation 
not permitted, unlink 'C:\wamp64\www\dev\node_modules\.staging'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 
\'C:\\wamp64\\www\\dev\\node_modules\\.staging\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\wamp64\\www\\dev\\node_modules\\.staging' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Akshay\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-12-
10T10_34_23_659Z-debug.log
```

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 
   'C:\wamp64\www\dev\node_modules.staging'

Comment: It's pretty clear - your login doesn't have permission to delete that file.  Perhaps it was created with administrator rights - If you run the install command as administrator it might work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and lots of npm users have the same problem. My experience is to downgrade my local npm version to 5.0.3 and it worked. For more details, please see this github post: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18380